# 2D array displayed on grid using windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to code a battleships game using windows forms in c# and the idea I have is to use a 2d-array with my ships and size and then somehow display it on the grid (inside the grid are buttons)

[image]

I have figured out how to get the position of the buttons and such like by using sender and then being able to change the color of them however I need to be able to "attach" my 2d-array with the ships to the grid and then change the buttons that have the ships to grey for the user, if you have any code to show me how to do this that would be great.

Comment: Have a look at `DataGridView`

Comment: You can have `List<Ship>` where each `Ship` has position (e.g. of `Point` type). To check cell you do *hit-test* (iterating over ships and check if there is any at given position). Try to separate view (`Form`) from model (`List<Ship>`) as much as you can, e.g. button should only operate with *position* (coordinate), *attaching* position to button can be done in many ways: 1) `control.Tag` 2) naming "buttonXY" and parsing it from name 3) creating 2d-array of buttons (`Button[][]`) to hold buttons in advance and use array *index* to determine position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the optimal solution, but:

Have you considered to have an array of objects such as

```
public class BattleCell{
    public Button HitButton{get;set;}
    public int Row{get;set;}
    public int Column{get;set;}
    public bool IsBombed{get;set;}
    public bool IsHit{get;set;}
}
```

The general idea is that you create a 2D array of "Cells" that contain the button to be pressed and modified. You can place the buttons on your grid programatically. You then have full control over other properties of that cell.

You would then construct a 2d Matrix like this

```
cells = new BattleCell[10, 10];
```

and fill them with relevant objects

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by mapping the array to the cells in the grid.

Assuming each cell has a number going from top-left to bottom-right, you could just index into the array based on the cell number.

The cell number could be set in the `Tag` property of the button.